# Creating a checkered background using lines and Graphics2D

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

I'm trying to create a background that's composed of lines horizontally and vertically with the same amount of gaps in between so that they look like squares.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SceneCanvas extends JComponent{
    private int width;
    private int height; 

    private Line backgroundLines[]= new Line[15];
    
    public SceneCanvas(int w, int h){
        this.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1024,768));

        width = w;
        height = h; 

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; 

        RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);

        Rectangle2D.Double bg = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,1024,768);
        g2d.setColor(new Color(130,107,75));
        g2d.fill(bg);

        int size = 50;
        int sizeUp = size+50;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int x = 50;
            int y1 = 0;
            int y2 = 1000;
            for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++){
                sizeUp = (size+50)*b;
                backgroundLines[i] = new Line(x*sizeUp, y1, x*sizeUp, y2,2, new Color (130,107,75));
                g2d.fill(backgroundLines[i]); // this line doesn't work
            }

          }
        Line2D.Double l1 = new Line2D.Double(50,0,50,1000);
        Line2D.Double l2 = new Line2D.Double(sizeUp,0,sizeUp,1000);
        Line2D.Double l3 = new Line2D.Double(sizeUp*1.5,0,sizeUp*1.5,1000);

        g2d.setColor(new Color(117,91,67));

        g2d.draw(l1);    
        g2d.draw(l2);
        g2d.draw(l3);

        

    }
}
```

I commented the line that doesn't work (the one that draws the lines repeatedly).

I made a for loop that takes in the same width n height for the lines but adjusts the gap in between based on the number of iterations the loop goes through (still ensures that they're the same amount of spaces in between)

Comment: What's `Line`??

Comment: If you want squares, then use the `fillRect(...)` method of the Graphcis object.